# Strange things happen with a time

Tags: php, date, time

I have recently bought VPS hosting and I assume, that it has problem with time. It sometimes changes, I guess. What could it be? How can I check whether it is true or not? Or it is just an error with my code? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean? Time changes every second, so that's no weird behaviour?

Comment: first of all! post your code :)

Comment: I have to do some sync as my hosting provider told me. How I do it? p.s. There are no problems with my code

Comment: is it windows or linux? would be great to post your code because its probably some error in code! :)

Comment: @FeRtoll : it is 100% the problem is not in my code. I have to do sync, my hosting provider told me. It is linux (centos). I have to write something in command line, but I can't find anything specific in google.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a wrong date/time set on your machine?: http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/time.html

Comment: The "time" that you get in your code is from clock of the server. Thus it may be different from the time on your computer.

Comment: The time is from server. How I do some sync? What is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure of the exact source of your problem but you probably mean you need to change the date and/or time of your VPS:

http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/time.html

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-time-from-linux-command-prompt/

Like:

```
# date --set="2 OCT 2006 18:00:00"
```

If this is the case, this question belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with PHP. Make php page with this content and upload it on your VPS:

```
<?php

 // show all informations
 phpinfo();

?>
```

or

```
<?php

 // Show just the module informations

 phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>
```

This will help you to see how php is configured on your VPS, and which functions you can to use, which not. If this isn't problem, please copy some code which make you problems.